# Create a separate app to combine the models from multiple apps?

Tags: django, django-models

I have multiple apps in my project which contain models which are related to each other.

For example:

- I have a crawler app which contains text which is crawled. (app 1)
- I have an images app which contains images which have been uploaded. (app 2)
- I have a color palettes app which generates color palettes based on images. (app 3)

The problem is all of the data is related.

For example, the crawled text (app 1) has a 1-to-1 relationship with an uploaded image (app 2), and a color palette (app 3) also has a 1-to-1 relationship with an uploaded image (app 2).

So right now my data is scattered across models in multiple apps.

Therefore I am thinking of creating a new app called "Data" whose job is just to contain the models from app 1, app 2 and app 3.

Is this considered a bad practice or does it make sense in my situation?

Thank you.

Comment: What's bad about having your models defined in different apps? What benefits would a `data` app to contain all models give you?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Our database structure is quite complex, and everything is quite tightly related. So having the models spread out between various apps is causing some issues, as it can be hard to mentally keep track of everything. At least if they're in one app, it's very clear to see everything together. So basically it's just to help keep things clearer. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can create relation models that will connect your separate models

```
class TextImage(models.Model):
    text = models.OneToOneField()
    image = models.OneToOneField()
```

Or use any other relation fields depending on what your needs are